# Get content of table in website with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get the content of a table on a website using selenium. It seems the website is set up in a rather complex manner. I can't find any element, class or content to use in the `find_element_by_...` functions.

If anyone has idea how to get the content of the second table starting with header `Staffel`, `Nr.`, `Datum`, `...`, `Ergebnis`, `Bem.` it would be a big help for me. I tried a lot (starting with urllib2, ...). Principally the following scripts works - loading the site and looping through high level containers. But I am not sure how to get the mentioned table content.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

the_url = 'https://www.hvw-online.org/spielbetrieb/ergebnissetabellen/#/league?ogId=3&lId=37133&allGames=1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(the_url)

elem_high = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'container')
for e in elem_high:
    print(e)

# what class or element to search for second table
elem_deep = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row.game')

driver.close()
```

Any ideas or comments are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rows you have to wait for page load using `WebDriverWait`, you can find details [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

the_url = 'https://www.hvw-online.org/spielbetrieb/ergebnissetabellen/#/league?ogId=3&lId=37133&allGames=1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get(the_url)

elem_deep = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.schedule tbody > tr")))
for e in elem_deep:
    print(e.text)
    # Link in last column
    href = e.find_element_by_css_selector("a[ng-if='row.game.sGID']").get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
```

But better solution is using `requests` package to get all information from website. Code below is example how you can scrape much faster and easier:

```
import requests

url = 'https://spo.handball4all.de/service/if_g_json.php?ca=1&cl=37133&cmd=ps&og=3'
response = requests.get(url).json()

futureGames = response[0]["content"]["futureGames"]["games"]
for game in futureGames:
    print(game["gHomeTeam"])
    print(game["gGuestTeam"])
    # Link in last column
    print("http://spo.handball4all.de/misc/sboPublicReports.php?sGID=%s" % game["sGID"])

    # You can use example of data below to get all you need
    # {
    #     'gID': '2799428',
    #     'sGID': '671616',
    #     'gNo': '61330',
    #     'live': False,
    #     'gToken': '',
    #     'gAppid': '',
    #     'gDate': '30.09.18',
    #     'gWDay': 'So',
    #     'gTime': '14:00',
    #     'gGymnasiumID': '303',
    #     'gGymnasiumNo': '6037',
    #     'gGymnasiumName': 'Sporthalle beim Sportzentrum',
    #     'gGymnasiumPostal': '71229',
    #     'gGymnasiumTown': 'Leonberg',
    #     'gGymnasiumStreet': 'Steinstraße 18',
    #     'gHomeTeam': 'SV Leonb/Elt',
    #     'gGuestTeam': 'JSG Echaz-Erms 2',
    #     'gHomeGoals': '33',
    #     'gGuestGoals': '20',
    #     'gHomeGoals_1': '19',
    #     'gGuestGoals_1': '7',
    #     'gHomePoints': '2',
    #     'gGuestPoints': '0',
    #     'gComment': ' ',
    #     'gGroupsortTxt': ' ',
    #     'gReferee': ' '
    # }
```

Comment: works great, thanks - one more thing: There is a link in the last column - why is it not shown in `e.text`. What do I need to change to get that?

Comment: How did you figure out the url. I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: devtools network tab. You can find `https://spo.handball4all.de/service/if_g_json.php` url and other part you can get from header

Answer (score 0):

You can use css class selector of

```
.schedule
```

That is:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".schedule")
```

You may need a wait before.

[image]

Then loop content

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url ='https://www.hvw-online.org/spielbetrieb/ergebnissetabellen/#/league?ogId=3&lId=37133&allGames=1'
driver.get(url)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.schedule')))
headers = [elem.text for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.schedule th')]
results = []
i = 1
for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    if i > 1:
        results.append([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
    i+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```